# snapd and SElinux

Tags: snap, apparmor, selinux

I have SElinux installed so obviously I can't install app armor but I'm trying to to install a snapd package and when I try to install snapd I get

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
apparmor
Suggested packages:
apparmor-profiles-extra apparmor-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
apparmor snapd
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 22.1 MB/22.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 96.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

if It's installing app armor the answer is obviously no but I do what to install snap. Is there a work around? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; so I've assumed *impish* - where you'll note `apparmor` is a *depends* requirement for `snapd`; as *snaps* were built around it.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/snapd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing and using SELinux on Ubuntu should be considered as an "advanced use-case", since Ubuntu uses AppArmor by default.

One of the consequences of using SELinux instead of AppArmor is that you loose `snapd` functionality, since `snapd` requires AppArmor, and can't use SELinux.

Also note that the SELinux packages for Ubuntu is in the "Universe" repository, which means they are maintained by the community and not Canonical.