# Is it safe to uninstall AppArmor?

Tags: apparmor

I made hardening my Ubuntu Laptop by usg tool and cis scripts.
Now I have a few strange issues in my work network environment. For example with NAC, DHCP client etc.
I would like to simplify my configuration.
Is it safe to completely uninstall AppArmor?

Ubuntu 20.04.4

Comment: Hello. With the information provided no good answer can be given. What did you do with this tool? What do the scripts do, what are their contents? What are the strange issues and be exact?

Comment: My question is whether it is generally possible to uninstall AppArmor without consequences (in the form of, for example, a system that will not start)?

Comment: "Hardening" and removing a MAC security module seem to be completely opposite things.

Comment: @muru yes - You are right.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who has spent the last few years becoming very familiar with AppArmor, let's go through the question as written in the comment in three parts:

**Q. My question is whether it is generally possible to uninstall AppArmor ...**

⇢ Yes, of course you can.

**Q. ... without consequences ...**

⇢ This is 100% dependent on what applications you have modified with regards to AppArmor policies. If, for example, you installed Apache and MySQL, configure AppArmor for these two systems, *but did not modify the Apache or MySQL `.conf` files to directly interact with AppArmor*, then you should have no issues. It is AppArmor that manages the software, not the other way around.

**Q. ... in the form of, for example, a system that will not start?**

⇢ See above. So long as you have not modified any of the software installed on the system to directly interact with AppArmor (checking permissions, policies, aliases, etc.), then you should be good to go.

---

As an aside, your question says that you hardened the installation "us[in]g tool[s] and cis scripts". If this is a mostly scripted mechanism for you, then a good way to test what will happen would be to build an Ubuntu Server installation within a virtual machine, harden the system, install and configure the software that is on the current server, then uninstall AppArmor to see what breaks. This is generally the approach that I take when helping a new client who has a server that I did not configure for them. Everything gets tested locally before being deployed on the production system.

Comment: Maybe an important aspect you should cover is that uninstalling AppArmor will break snap functionality completely, since `snapd` requires AppArmor. Also see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378178/snapd-and-selinux/) and [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/snapd).

Comment: You raise a good point. I had thought the question was discussing Ubuntu Server for some reason. Will need to make some edits ...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  For server it can be an issue as well (depending on your needs) - for instance Livepatch, Multipass and LXD are only distributed as snaps.

Comment: Thank You for clarification.

Comment: By my "hardening" I mean to simply run this scripts (without manually modification ane app especially for AppArmor) https://ubuntu.com/security/certifications/docs/usg/cis/audit